# Возможности CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mvc

Хотелось бы узнать что можно сделать на это фреймворке, какие уже готовые проекты есть.
Какие дополнительные инструменты использовать?
Понравилось именно что есть паттерн MVC и поддержка различных баз данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Возможности CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/features.html) и [готовые проекты](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Applications_Using_Code_Igniter/). Никаких принципиальных отличий от [многочисленных аналогичных фреймворках](http://www.google.ru/search?q=php+framework), на мой взгляд, не имеет.

Comment: А вы не знаете онлайн готовые проекты на нем?
Специализируюсь в основном на веб-разработке.

Comment: Ну т.к. это фрейморк на php, то все проекты на нем онлайновые, в т.ч. и проекты из списка выше. Или что вы имеете ввиду под онлайновыми проектами?

Comment: Я имел ввиду что то вроде рабочих сайтов.

Comment: Ну а чем сайты по этой ссылке не рабочие: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Applications_Using_Code_Igniter/ ?

Comment: А сори я чет не туда посмотрел.
Начинаем разворачивать свой проект)